# Webservice Http Authentication - KSOAP2 on Android

Tags: android, web-services, authentication, http-headers, android-ksoap2

I have been searching the web for a while now, but wasn't able to find a appropriate solution for my problem. This article does not really help either, because the classes and methods used are not present in ksoap2 for android: [Basic HTTP authentication using KSOAP for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177939/basic-http-authentication-using-ksoap-for-android)

I am trying to access a SAP webservice, which I set up in the sap soa manager. The webservice requires basic authentication in the http header. Accessing this web service by soapUI is not a problem, because it is possible to set up http authentication there.

My Problem:
I want to access the web service with a android device and I want to use KSOAP2 for Android because I already have some experience with that libary. My problem is that I don't know how to authenticate to the webservice?

Has anyone had a similar problem and knows how to solve it?
I would be grateful if you could help me!

Answer (score 6):

I hope it is not too late. That is how I access SAP webservice with KSOAP:

```
List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic XXXXXXXXXX"));
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
Object result = null;               
final Object response = androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headers);
```

Replace the XXXXXXXX with the encoded hash of your username and password. To get it just look in soapUI raw header request. Hope it helps.

Comment: If the Authorization is windows, is it possible ??

Comment: @arun have u got the solution for windows authentication because i need to do in my project

Comment: @PushpaRaja.No, using Ksoap2 we will not bel able to do this. So the solutions is to do it in the server side part.