# Cannot authenticate wcf service in android

Tags: java, android, wcf, web-services, authentication

My application is calling wcf service.but it un suscess. I would like to implement an authentication method which sends username and password to server and a server sends response, but it not work.
Here is logdebug :

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:0 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40531b28)
```

Code check authenticate:

```
public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
   {
    if (userName == null || password == null)
     {
      throw new ArgumentNullException();
     }    
      Account account = new Account();
      bool success = account.Login(userName, password);    
      LogSystem log = new LogSystem();
      log.LogToFile(userName + ":" + password);

      bool success = (userName == "admin" && password == "admin");
        if (!success)
         {
          throw new FaultException("wrong user or pass");
          }
   }
```

Here mycode client :

```
 try {
   SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);        
   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                                                         SoapEnvelope.VER10);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    Element userName = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "userName");
    userName.addChild(Node.TEXT, "admin");
    userName.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
    Element password = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "password");
    password.addChild(Node.TEXT, "admin");
    password.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);

    envelope.headerOut = new Element[2];
    envelope.headerOut[0] = userName;
    envelope.headerOut[1] = password;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    String xmlString = envelope.getResponse().toString();
    Log.e("NewWS", " " + xmlString);
    tv1.setText(androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
    } catch (Exception E) {
        E.printStackTrace();

}
```

I don't know bescaus this.
i try [how to set soap Header using ksoap2 - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613675/how-to-set-soap-header-using-ksoap2-android)  but it's not work for me.
please help me .
Many thanks.

Comment: This is a common problem with WCF webservices.See the link below and you'll get that you are not alone who is facing this problem.... http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=26