# Soap request creation using ksoap2 for multilevel tags

Tags: java, android, soap-client, ksoap2, android-webservice

I want to build a soap request using KSOAP2 for android application. how to create a request for the given below soap request.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:glob="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global" 
 xmlns:yrt="http://0021611689-one-off.sap.com/YRTWIVFXY_" 
 xmlns:ytk="http://0021611689-one-off.sap.com/YTK2PLNNY_" 
 xmlns:glob1="http://sap.com/xi/AP/Globalization">`
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <glob:CustomerBundleMaintainRequest_sync_V1>
  <BasicMessageHeader>
    </BasicMessageHeader>
     <Customer>
        <InternalID>234569</InternalID>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <CategoryCode>1</CategoryCode>
        <CustomerIndicator>true</CustomerIndicator>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <LifeCycleStatusCode>2</LifeCycleStatusCode>
        <!--Optional:-->

     </Customer>
    </glob:CustomerBundleMaintainRequest_sync_V1>
    </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have written the Android code and tried to build the request it shows an error that Soapfault message error. Find below the android code

```
    public class CreateCustomer {

        public void createCustomerAccount() throws IOException {

            SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(NAME_SPACE,METHOD_NAME);
            soapObject.addProperty("InternalID","98765");
            soapObject.addProperty("CategoryCode","1");
            soapObject.addProperty("CustomerIndicator","true");
            soapObject.addProperty("LifeCycleStatusCode","2");
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For Building soap request ..

```
public String sendSoapRequest(Context c) throws Exception {


    String finalString = "Paste your whole request through which you can send request from browser sucessfully";
    Log.i("TAG", "*********************** FinalString Before "
            + FinalString);



    // send SOAP request
    InputStream resInputStream = sendRequest(FinalString);

    // create the response SOAP envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    // process SOAP response
    parseResponse(resInputStream, envelope);

    Object bodyIn = envelope.bodyIn;

    SoapObject RequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
    String response = RequestSOAP.getProperty(0).toString();
    if (bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
        throw (SoapFault) bodyIn;
    }
    return response.toString();
}
```

> calling sendRequest ..

```
 private InputStream sendRequest(String requestContent) throws Exception {

    // initialize HTTP post
    HttpPost httpPost = null;

    try {
        httpPost = new HttpPost(PostURL);

        httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
        httpPost.addHeader("SOAPAction", "Your Soap Action");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Error initializing HTTP post for SOAP request", e);
        // throw e;
    }

    // load content to be sent
    try {
        HttpEntity postEntity = new StringEntity(requestContent);
        httpPost.setEntity(postEntity);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("LOG_TAG",
                "Unsupported ensoding of content for SOAP request", e);
        throw e;
    }

    // send request
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Error sending SOAP request", e);
        // throw e;
    }

    // get SOAP response
    try {
        // get response code
        int responseStatusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine()
                .getStatusCode();

        // if the response code is not 200 - OK, or 500 - Internal error,
        // then communication error occurred
        if (responseStatusCode != 200 && responseStatusCode != 500) {
            String errorMsg = "Got SOAP response code "
                    + responseStatusCode + " "
                    + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
            // ...
        }

        // get the response content
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
        return is;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Error getting SOAP response", e);
        // throw e;
    }
    return null;
}
```

> call parseResponse

```
  /**
 * Parses the input stream from the response into SoapEnvelope object.
 */
private void parseResponse(InputStream is, SoapEnvelope envelope)
        throws Exception {

    try {
        XmlPullParser xp = new KXmlParser();
        xp.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, true);
        xp.setInput(is, "UTF-8");
        envelope.parse(xp);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Error reading/parsing SOAP response", e);

    }

}
```

> call SendOrderDetails...

```
 private class SendOrderDetails extends AsyncTask<String, CartViewItemsBean, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        String fdfd = "";
        try {
            fdfd = sendSoapRequest(getActivity());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return fdfd;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Log.i("transactionresponse", result);

        if (!result.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            try {
                helpher.deleteTotalRecord();
                String ffsd = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + result.toString();
                XmlToJson xmlToJson = new XmlToJson.Builder(ffsd.trim()).build();
                JSONObject jsonObject = xmlToJson.toJson();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {

        }


    }
}
```

> And you have to use library XmlToJson
>    finally you have to call this using

```
new SendOrderDetails().execute();
```