# Custom header with Ksoap2

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I need my header to look like this:

```
  <soap:Header>
    <ListAuthenticationHeader XmlAttribute="" xmlns="http://example.com/services">
      <ApiKey>1234567890</ApiKey>
    </ListAuthenticationHeader>
  </soap:Header>
```

I tried

```
List<HeaderProperty> headerPropertyList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
headerPropertyList.add(new HeaderProperty("ApiKey","1234567890"));
HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerPropertyList);
```

but that doesn't work, server responds with access denied.

Comment: I havn't tried this , hope it will work .. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6641272/1037078

Comment: That worked. Wonder why I didn't find that question via google. Thanks a lot!

Comment: :) .. happens sometimes .. pls close the question ...