# Web service receives an empty SOAP

Tags: android, web-services, authentication, soap

My android mobile app communicates with web methods. They require user's authentication so I send username and password inside SOAP header as in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613675/how-to-set-soap-header-using-ksoap2-android). I've checked it and it generated correctly

```
    <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
            xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <v:Header>
            <n0:AuthHeader xmlns:n0="http://tempuri.org/">
                <n0:user>x</n0:user>
                <n0:pass>y</n0:pass>
            </n0:AuthHeader>
        </v:Header>
        <v:Body>
            <AuthenticationUser xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1" />
        </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

But on the server side, the web method `AuthenticationUser()` receives an empty SOAP.

```
        [WebMethod]
    [SoapHeader("SoapHeader")]
    public string AuthenticationUser()
    {
        if (SoapHeader == null)
            return "Please provide Username and Password !" ;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SoapHeader.userName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(SoapHeader.password))
            return "Please provide Username and Password !!" ;

        //Check is User credentials Valid
        if (!SoapHeader.IsUserCredentialsValid(SoapHeader.userName, SoapHeader.password))
            return "Invalid Username or Password !!!";

        // Create and store the AuthenticatedToken before returning it
        string token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(
            token,
            SoapHeader.userName,
            null,
            System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
            null
            );
        return token;
    }
```

I get the response from `AuthenticationUser()` web method in my app

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <AuthenticationUserResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <AuthenticationUserResult>
                Please provide Username and Password !
            </AuthenticationUserResult>
        </AuthenticationUserResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I don't know why did `AuthenticationUser()` web method receive empty SOAP?? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: print the response and see what it is there.

Comment: I did. See the above XML, it returns `Please provide Username and Password ! ` which is returned when the SOAP header is null                       `if (SoapHeader == null)
            return "Please provide Username and Password !" ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my mistake. I did not pay attention for tags. I was trying to send `authHeader` with `user` and `pass`

```
<n0:AuthHeader xmlns:n0="http://tempuri.org/">
            <n0:user>x</n0:user>
            <n0:pass>y</n0:pass>
</n0:AuthHeader>
```

where it must be `SecuredTokenWebservice` with `userName` and `password`

```
 <SecuredTokenWebservice xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <userName>x</userName>
            <password>y</password>
</SecuredTokenWebservice>
```